# Масштабирование SVG карты страны относительно выбранного округа

Tags: javascript, html, css3, анимация, svg

Есть SVG карта страны. Нужно достичь эффекта, чтобы при клике на округе происходило бы масштабирование относительно центра выбранного округа, т.е. `transfrom-origin` должен находится в центре выбранного округа. Хотелось бы обойтись **без каких-либо библиотек**.

1. Первый вопрос это почему [**здесь**](https://jsfiddle.net/smokir/bo73g53y/), когда задано значение `viewBox`, то `polygon`'ы построенные по точкам, полученным от `getBoundingClientRect()`, не совпадают с самими элементами `svg`, `map` и `e.target`?
2. Если добавлять коэффициенты, как [**тут**](https://jsfiddle.net/smokir/6hya23p8/), то какие тогда должны быть значения у `viewBoxMapCoefX1` и `viewBoxMapCoefX1`, чтобы полученный `mapPolygon` совпадал с `map`?
3. Если масштабировать `map` с помощью:

   ```
   // ANIMATION HERE
   map.style.transformOrigin = transformOriginX + "px " + transformOriginY + "px";
   map.style.transform = "scale(" + scale + ")";
   ```

   то выглядит так, как будто значение `transformOrigin` неверное. Если попытаться изменить *viewBox*:

   ```
   // ANIMATION HERE
   svg.viewBox.baseVal.x = bounding.left;
   svg.viewBox.baseVal.y = bounding.top;
   svg.viewBox.baseVal.width = bounding.width;
   svg.viewBox.baseVal.height = bounding.height;
   ```

   то как тогда можно сделать плавную анимацию масштабирования только средствами CSS (**без SMIL**)?

Буду благодарен любой помощи и советам по делу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Нужно использовать `.getBBox()` вместо `getBoundingClientRect()`, чтобы получить координаты относительно самого SVG, а не экрана. [**Результат**](https://jsfiddle.net/smokir/s6f3arot/).

3) Вместо масштабирования карты относительно центра выбранного субъекта (`transformOrigin` + `scale`) можно центр субъекта получить в `%` вместо `px` и переместить в центр карты, а потом сделать масштабирование, т.е.:

```
// ANIMATION HERE
var transformOriginXPercent = (50 - transformOriginX * 100 / mapBounding.width) * scale;
var transformOriginYPercent = (50 - transformOriginY * 100 / mapBounding.height) * scale;
var scaleText = "scale(" + scale + ")";
var translateText = "translate(" + transformOriginXPercent + "%," + transformOriginYPercent + "%)";

map.style.transformOrigin = "50% 50%";
map.style.transform = translateText + " " + scaleText;
```

и тем самым достичь нужного [**результата**](https://jsfiddle.net/smokir/35qycv6x/).

В целом вопрос решен, однако интересно, как можно достичь этого же эффекта с помощью:

```
map.style.transformOrigin = (transformOriginX) + "px " + (transformOriginY) + "px";
map.style.transform = "scale(" + scale + ")";
```

подобрав правильные коэффициенты для `transformOriginX` и `transformOriginY`